# using jquery autocomplete i am trying to get the value in the text box as table the datas are not coming from json using ajax in the text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, autocomplete

This is the first time I am using ajax with json for autocomplete (Jquery) the result will look like the auto-complete but the structure(output) will look like table.

Here is my jquery code

```
$("document").ready(function (){
   $(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "dummy.json",
        success: function(){
            alert("got the file");  
        },
          error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
              console.log(xhr.status);
              console.log(thrownError);
          }

    });
    return false;
   });
});
```

Here is my json data

```
{  
 "schoolname":{  
  "school":[  
     {  
        "id":"1",
        "description":"COL000001",
        "schoolname":"Emirates College of Technology- UAE"
     },
     {  
        "id":"2",
        "description":"COL000002",
        "schoolname":"Al Khawarizmi International College- UAE"
     },
     {  
        "id":"3",
        "description":"COL000003",
        "schoolname":"Syscoms College"
     },
     {  
        "id":"4",
        "description":"Other",
        "schoolname":"Other 1"
     }
  ]
 }
}
```

I am getting an error in firefox for console.log(xhr.status); 200 and console.log(thrownError); Invalid XML:

I am new this I confused why this was not working I tried putting console.log in error function

This is my html code where my autocomplete

```
<input type="text" class="ipt_Field" id="scl_name">
```

Thanks in advance
Mahadevan

Comment: Most likely your server is serving the json file with the wrong MIME type. Adding `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax configuration may solve it. If not, you need to configure your server to serve json correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can occur if the AJAX call interprets your data as XML rather than JSON. To solve this, try specifying the **dataType** for your AJAX call. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "dummy.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function() {
        alert("got the file");  
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
    }
});
```

Also, consider using **http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/**.

EDIT: **contentType** is used when data is sent to the server. And, **dataType** is used when data is retrieved from the server.

Comment: This is incorrect. `contentType` is the type being _sent to_ the server. `dataType` is the type being _returned_.

Comment: @SexyTurnip - ahh yes! you are correct. I am fixing my answer.