# Using an external auto complete plugin (jQuery) and i am trying to put my own value in json it was not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jquery-autocomplete

This is the continuation with my previous question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253673/using-jquery-autocomplete-i-am-trying-to-get-the-value-in-the-text-box-as-table/34253789#34253789) I am new to the JSON and ajax trying to put my own value in this [link](http://vyasrao.github.io/tAutocomplete/)  the data as per my requirement.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
$.widget('custom.mcautocomplete', $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
        var self = this,
            thead;

        if (this.options.showHeader) {
            table = $('<div class="ui-widget-header" style="width:100%"></div>');
            $.each(this.options.columns, function(index, item) {
                table.append('<span style="padding:0 4px;float:left;width:' + item.width + ';">' + item.name + '</span>');
            });
            table.append('<div style="clear: both;"></div>');
            ul.append(table);
        }
        $.each(items, function(index, item) {
            self._renderItem(ul, item);
        });
    },
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
        var t = '',
            result = '';

        $.each(this.options.columns, function(index, column) {
            t += '<span style="padding:0 4px;float:left;width:' + column.width + ';">' + item[column.valueField ? column.valueField : index] + '</span>'
        });

        result = $('<li></li>').data('item.autocomplete', item).append('<a class="mcacAnchor">' + t + '<div style="clear: both;"></div></a>').appendTo(ul);
        return result;
    }
});
//from here I am customizing the code*/
  $("document").ready(function (){
   $("#scl_name").mcautocomplete({
    // These next two options are what this plugin adds to the autocomplete widget.
    showHeader: true,
       showHeader: true,
        columns: [{
            name: 'description',
            width: '150px'
        }, {
            name: 'schoolname',
            width: '120px'
        }],

    // Event handler for when a list item is selected.
    /*select: function (event, ui) {
        this.value = (ui.item ? ui.item.name : '');
        $('#school_Name').text(ui.item ? 'Selected: ' + ui.item.name +this.value);
        return false;
    },*/

    // The rest of the options are for configuring the ajax webservice call.
    minLength: 1,
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'dummy.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                featureClass: 'P',
                style: 'full',
                maxRows: 12,
                name_startsWith: request.term,
                username: "demo"
            },
            // The success event handler will display "No match found" if no items are returned.
            success: function (data) {
                var result;
                if (!data || data.length === 0 || !data.schoolname || data.schoolname.length === 0) {
                    result = [{
                        label: 'No match found.'
                    }];
                } else {
                    result = data.schoolname;
                    console.log(result);
                }
                response(result);
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

with the current one i am getting the output as [object]
 Now  I am not getting any error but i am not getting any value as well :(
    This is my html

```
<input type="text" id="scl_name" class="ipt_Field"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is this 'eval()' in here and Why You want use this? And for so far I can see I can not figure out from where this 'schoolname1' is coming from. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: if your creating a Regular expression you should use 'new RegExp'
`var searchData = new RegExp( schoolname1.searchdata(), "gi");`

Comment: @Franco schoolname1 is var for text box id

Comment: @synthet1c here i am trying using if (v.description.search(new RegExp(searchData)) != -1) {